# Autocomplete of Groovy in Eclipse Oxygen Changes What I Type

Tags: eclipse, groovy

In Eclipse (JEE) Oxygen I have the following plugins installed, other than what comes out of the box with a Java EE distribution of Eclipse:

- [groovy-eclipse](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/wiki) for Oxygen (4.7) - Snapshot version as of November 8, 2017
- [Spring Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-tools-aka-spring-ide-and-spring-tool-suite) for Oxygen - version from Marketplace as of November 8, 2017

I am coding in Groovy in .groovy files (created using New -> Groovy Class) and I very frequently get extremely weird and undesired autocomplete behavior.

**Example 1**

If I type `System.out.` on a new line, Eclipse autocompletes it to `System.out0.` (notice the `0`). This is a private field of the `System` class and should definitely not be there.

To get rid of it, I can't just backspace and try the `.` again, or it'll put it back. I have to <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, then hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then hit `.` to get it to read `System.out.`.

**Example 2**

In JUnit, I have in my class the following field:

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException ex = ExpectedException.none()
```

When inside a method body on a new line I type `ex.expect(` I see the autocomplete window pop up, and the first result is a member named `anyExceptionExpected`. Predictably, when I continue typing anything as an argument to the method, or type <kbd>)</kbd>, Eclipse replaces what is a perfectly reasonable method call with: `ex.anyExceptionExpected(`.

Again, hammering <kbd>Esc</kbd> "fixes" the problem, but what bothers me is that I *shouldn't have to* constantly hammer <kbd>Esc</kbd> to keep Eclipse from replacing perfectly valid code with total nonsense just because it's the first asciibetical hit in the list of member names of the object that happens to have the member name I typed as a substring.

Eclipse in Java *certainly* doesn't have this extremely oppressive behavior. Java autocomplete does not get in your way. You can blow through and type out your statements "raw" (without any autocomplete) when you don't want it, as if you're typing in plain vanilla Notepad, and Eclipse for Java generally won't mess with your code too much (except for sometimes making life harder by automatically adding closing parentheses or quotation marks when they are not wanted, but that's minor, since sometimes it's beneficial).

So why won't Eclipse for Groovy do the same? Is there a setting somewhere in the sprawling Preferences pane of Eclipse where I can tweak this behavior for Groovy code?

Basically I want Eclipse Groovy's autocompletion feature to work just like the default Eclipse Java autocomplete (meaning, the behavior you get with a default Eclipse install, a clean Eclipse workspace and without making any preference changes). How can I do this?

Comment: The same thing is happening to me.  I have Eclipse Oxygen J2SE (not JEE), with EGradle and groovy-eclipse, but not Spring Tools

Answer (score 0):

If you disable a couple of code assist options, proposals and completions will only occur when you explicitly request them.

Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist :
  uncheck "Enable auto activation"
  uncheck "Insert single proposals automatically"